# Is there a Maven repository for Solace artifacts?

Tags: maven, solace, solace-mq

I'm trying to find out whether there is a Maven repository for Solace artifacts. From what I've checked, these are not available via Maven Central. We'd like to proxy these via our Nexus repository manager. If they aren't available, I suppose we'll have to add them to our third-party hosted repository. I'm just checking what the proper course of action should be.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't look like it (at least I couldn't find anything either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solace Systems does not currently provide a Maven repository for Solace artifacts. I recommend adding the Solace JARs manually to your repository.

The JARs are contained in their associated API package. You can find the download links for these API packages on the Solace developer portal.

Edit: Solace does now provide a Maven repository for Solace artifacts as of December 2016.

Comment: Thanks for the official confirmation. Are there any plans to provide a Maven repository? Also, where can I find the licensing information for these libraries?

Comment: Solace has no current plans to provide a Maven repository. You can find the licensing information in the pop-up when you download any of the libraries.

Comment: Where can I get the source code for api, for debuging issue.

Comment: @AlexandraMasse: Could you please check my comments on the answer given by @Sasi.SP? It would be great, if your guys could: a) put examples of the Maven `<dependency/>` sections; b) add details on the Maven coordinates for the artifacts, because the search link is broken; c) add older versions of the Solace artifacts as well for companies that can't currently switch to the latest version.

Comment: @carlspring The Solace Java tutorials all contain examples of the Maven dependency sections. The tutorials are available here: http://dev.solace.com/get-started/java-tutorials/. Alternatively, you can see the dependency section right on the artifact page here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.solacesystems/sol-jcsmp/10.0.0. There was an issue in the past with the search link but it should be available now.

Comment: @carlspring Solace will not be retrofitting old versions of the API, please use version 10.0 or later if you want to build with Maven. Note that the 10.0 API is fully backwards compatible with all supported message router versions.

Answer (score 2):

Now its available. Please find the details in [this link](https://solace.com/blog/products-tech/solace-apis-maven-central) .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. For the future, here is some information, how to crack a awesome answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Sasi.SP: I don't know, if you're the author of the page you've linked to, but the links to the Maven Search page are broken. Under what GAV are the artifacts uploaded? From what I can see, the `groupId` is not `solacesystems`, but `com.solacesystems` (check here (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/solacesystems/) for a link to the artifacts in the repository and here (http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.solacesystems%22) for the results via the search engine).

Comment: Also, it looks like the Maven index has not been updated yet, so the search engine's results are not working.